# pip install is not working correctly. Constant retrying errors and unable to find any versions which satisfy the requirement

Tags: pip, anaconda, virtualenv

I am currently working using Anaconda Prompt and attempting to run the DeepLabCut Software. While doing my typical `pip install deeplabcut` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.10` I am receiving this message:

DLC is the virtual environment I created through Anaconda which utilized python version 3.6

```
(DLC) C:\Users\SaundersLab>pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.10
Collecting tensorflow-gpu==1.10
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow-gpu/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow-gpu/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow-gpu/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow-gpu/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow-gpu/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.10 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.10
```

Prior to today, I was able to download all of the pip components without an issue, but now I am unable to download anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

From [tensorflow.org](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

[image]

Also you can try `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow` [link](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow).